# Can we provide IP address data that might not be the user's data?

Tags: gdpr, privacy

We have a user who is being harassed by somebody and on our service, the harasser filled out the user's password reset form.

This created a log entry that essentially says

> <Harasser's IP address> initiated a password reset for <User's Username>. Instructions were mailed to <User's Full email address>.

We would like to provide this data to the user who is being harassed so they can pursue it with the internet provider to see if they can figure out who is harassing them.

However, we're unsure if this data is considered somebody else's PII, and thus we cannot give out this information.

Would the harasser have a case against us for giving out their IP address to the user they are harassing?

Comment: Privacy law varies.  What jurisdiction would the site be located in, or run from? Do you kn ow what jurisdiction the IP address is located in, or at least geolocates to? If so, which one?

Comment: How do you know that the IP address you have belongs to a person who is harassing your user?

Comment: The site runs in the US. The user, and the IP address originate from the same country in the European Economic Area, and are thus covered by GDPR (sorry I failed to mention that in the question, I only tagged the question with that.). The user told us that a harasser had triggered their password reset button, and this log entry is the only instance of that. We really dont know *who* owns that IP.   But we presume its the harassers.

Comment: @Mixologic keep this simple - the "harasser" claimed to be the user to carry out the password reset request and you have no evidence that they are not, so in your eyes they are.  No judgement necessary.

Comment: Frankly I would say don't bother, it simply isn't useful information, and the likelihood that something bad might happen as a result of you passing along an IP address is just too high. Do a search for problems surrounding IP lookup services. Often times these services will give generic addresses when they can't identify a specific location.

Comment: @Moo The phrase "*a user who is being harassed by somebody*" suggests that the OP might have additional information supporting his conclusion that harassment is indeed taking place.

Comment: @Kommissar "*Often times these services will give generic addresses*". Agreed, but the OP's log entries might contain additional information such as date and timestamp which facilitates piecing together harasser's course of conduct. Harassers typically don't limit themselves to only one platform or method, whence the OP's notification might prompt the OP to also look out for harasser's possible acts elsewhere.

Comment: @IñakiViggers yes, but thats the users side of things - from the service providers side of things, the "harasser" is posing as the user, and you have absolutely no way to know which unauthenticated request is actually the user and which are not - the IP address being from Europe, China, Russia doesnt mean anything because the structure of the internet can and does change depending on BGP routing, with traffic being pushed through odd routes fairly often (for example, China and Russia have both stolen huge chunks of routes fairly recently) and things like VPNs complicate matters.

Comment: @Moo "*no way to know which unauthenticated request is actually the user and which are not*" If it were actually the harassed user, there is no harm because it means the OP is not disclosing to third parties. And if it were the harasser, the GDPR is unavailing to him because the law is not intended to facilitate harasser's unlawful conduct. (Otherwise, I'm not sure I'm following you).

Comment: @IñakiViggers Im saying that the service has no way to realistically 100% authenticate which of the requests is truly not the user and which are, and given the "harasser" posed as the "harassed" user then I'm pretty sure no EU data protection office would have any issues with the "harassed" user receiving the IP address of the "harasser" in this case.  If the "harassed" user had not mentioned the harassment, the service would have just handed it over anyway.  So the simple solution is to hand over all the requests made to the "harassed" user.

Comment: @Moo "*the simple solution is to hand over all the requests made to the "harassed" user*". That's exactly what the OP has in mind. He wrote: "*We would like to provide this data to the user who is being harassed*". He just needed to know whether he could get in trouble for doing so. The answer is No.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Would the harasser have a case against us for giving out their IP address to the user they are harassing?

No, but it is important that you preserve evidence of the harassment regardless of what you and/or the harassed user decide. A wrongdoer is not allowed to use the GDPR or any other legislation as a shield apropos of his unlawful conduct.

[GDPR](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/eli/reg/2016/679/oj) in its article 6.1(f) permits "*processing [that] is necessary for the purposes of the legitimate interests pursued [...] by a third party*" (brackets added). The harassed person obviously has a legitimate interest in knowing who is harassing him and purportedly trying to cause him additional trouble.

To be safe, you might want to first ask the harassed user whether he intends to pursue the matter with the ISP, with Law Enforcement, and/or take legal action. Only if he answers in the affirmative, provide the relevant records.